# Load text to webpage from third party

Tags: text, web, load

As a complete beginner, I´m starting a web project running multiple website that should show the same text, that is regulary edited. Where the "source text" should be hosted depends on what's best.

I´ve heard of solutions such as RSS and Java. It would be great making it load as fast as possible, but initially I just want it to work.

Thankful for tips, ideas and help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would have to be connected to a database